# Sql query to return elements with same ID as comma separated string

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables, `table1` has a `entry_ID`, `entry_date` and other entry information. `table2` has `entry_ID` and `entry_subject`. Each `entry_ID` can have arbitrarily many `entry_subjects`.

I want a query that will return an `entry_ID`, `entry_date`, and a list of the subjects corresponding to that entry separated by commas.

The first step in this seems to be just getting a query that returns an `entry_ID` and a comma separated list of subjects from `table2`. Once I have that the join should be easy.
I adapted the [recursive CTE method from this site](http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/rowconcatenate.aspx): to fit my case:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE (entry_ID, subjectlist, subject, length)
    AS ( SELECT entry_ID, cast( '' as varchar(8000))
                        , cast( '' as varchar(8000)), 0
         FROM table2 
         GROUP BY entry_ID
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT t2.entry_ID, 
             cast(subjectlist || CASE length = 0 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END
                              || entry_subject AS varchar(8000) ),
             cast (t2.entry_subject as varchar(8000)),
             length +1
         FROM CTE c 
         INNER JOIN table2 t2 
             on c.entry_ID=t2.entry_ID where t2.entry_subject > c.subject)
SELECT entry_ID, subjectlist FROM (
    SELECT entry_ID, subjectlist, RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY entry_ID order by length DESC)
    FROM CTE) D (entry_ID, subjectlist, rank) where rank = 1;
```

And it works, I get the response I expect. To achieve my final goal the query I use is this:

```
SELECT t1.* t2.subjectlist FROM table1 
    JOIN (ABOVE QUERY) AS t2 on t1.entry_ID=t2.entry_ID;
```

This seems very unwieldy. Is this really the best way to do this?

Comment: Personally, I'd do this in a middle layer, off the database, if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by middle layer? I suppose I could do this much more easily in a bash script that makes database calls, but I'm using a utility library that takes input strings that it interprets as querys and executes directly in the appropriate database.

Comment: Oh, I didn't get that distinction. Yes thats what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then there should be a **much simpler** solution.

#### Test setup

According to your description - you could have done that for us:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   entry_id int4 PRIMARY KEY
 , entry_date date
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
   entry_id int4 REFERENCES table1 (entry_id)
 , entry_subject text
 , PRIMARY KEY (entry_id, entry_subject)
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, '2011-09-01'), (2, '2011-09-02'),(3, '2011-09-03');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, 'foo1'), (2, 'foo2'), (2, 'bar2')
                        , (3, 'foo3'), (3, 'baz3'), (3, 'bar3');
```

#### Answer

`string_agg()` requires Postgres 9.0+

```
SELECT t1.entry_id, t1.entry_date
     , string_agg(t2.entry_subject, ', ') AS entry_subjects
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 USING (entry_id)
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1;

 entry_id | entry_date | entry_subjects
----------+------------+------------------
        1 | 2011-09-01 | foo1
        2 | 2011-09-02 | bar2, foo2
        3 | 2011-09-03 | baz3, bar3, foo3
```

Or, if you want the entry_subjects **sorted**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       t1.entry_id
     , t1.entry_date
     , string_agg(t2.entry_subject, ', ') OVER (
          PARTITION BY t1.entry_id ORDER BY t2.entry_subject
          RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                    AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS entry_subjects
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 USING (entry_id)
  ORDER BY 1;

 entry_id | entry_date | entry_subjects
----------+------------+------------------
        1 | 2011-09-01 | foo1
        2 | 2011-09-02 | bar2, foo2
        3 | 2011-09-03 | bar3, baz3, foo3
```

You could do the same with a subselect on `table2` to first `ORDER BY entry_subject`.

Comment: The string_agg function was only introduced in postgres 9.0, and I have an earlier version. However, this gave me the idea to use a combination of array_to_string and array_agg to do the same thing that string_agg does. Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: Yeah, string_agg() is just a (very convenient) shortcut for array_to_string(array_agg(..))